# java programm thats initialise the values of an 2 diemnsonal array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to write a programm by using a 2d imensional array were you able to type in how many students are in a classroomm . Next step would be that every student has a different number of grades so the out print should look like this example :

> Number of Students : 3
>
> 1.Student  -> First Grade : 5; Second Grade :3; Third Grade : 2;
>   2.Student First Grade : 1;
>   3.Student  First Grade : 6; Second Grade: 2;

Question: My Programm stops at the point were every student should get a different number of notes . I don`t get it why zeile[i] can´t take the values of i  so zeile[0] would get the first value zeile[1] get the second and so on . The same problem at spalte[n].

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NotenZeugnis {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        int zeile,spalte;
        int Noten [] [];
        int anzahlS ;
        int anzahl[];

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Bitte geben sie die Anzahl der Schüler ein : ");
        anzahlS = in.nextInt();//EINGABE DER SCHÜLER BSP .3 DANN 3 ZEILEN {{},{},{}};

        for (int i = 0; i <= anzahlS - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println("Wieviele Noten hat der " + (i+1) +".Schüler ?");
            zeile[i] = in.nextInt();//EINGABE DER ANZAHL DER NOTEN  
            System.out.println(zeile);}
            for (int s = 0; s < Noten[zeile].length; s++) { //I LASSEN WIR HIERBEI SO OFT LAUFEN WIE DIE ANZAHL DER NOTEN BSP 3 DANN GEHEN 
                //WIR DIESE SCHLEIFE 4 MAL DRUCH
                System.out.println("Bitte geben sie die Noten für die ");
                spalte[s] = in.nextInt();} //DABEI ERHÄLT SPALTE 0 EINEN WERT SPALTE 1 EINEN WERT SPALTE 2
                Noten = new int [zeile][spalte];    
            }
    }

// WAS ICH IMPLEMENTIEREN MÖCHTE 
//MAN SOLL EINE ANZAHL VON SCHÜLERN ANGEBEN 
//FÜR DIESE ANZAHL SOLL ER MICH JEWEILS FRAGEN WIE VIELE NOTEN DIESE SCHÜLER HABEN------BIS HIER HIN GESCHAFFT
//UND DABEI IMMER DIESE WERTE DEN SCHÜLERN ZUORDNEN DABEI SOLLEN DIESE WERTE DAS ERSTE FELD ÜBERNEHMEN
//SODASS BSP. 3 SCHÜLER 1.SCHÜLER HAT 3 NOTEN 2.SCHÜLER 2 NOTEN 3.SCHÜLER HAT 5 NOTEN 
//BEI AUSGABE VON FELD ZEILE SOLLTE DER COMPUTER DAS JETZT SO WISSEN
//zeile[0]=3;
//zeile[1]=2;
//zeile[2]=5;
```

Question: My Programm stops at the point were every student should get a different number of notes . I don`t get it why zeile[i] can´t take the values of i  so zeile[0] would get the first value zeile[1] get the second and so on . The same problem at spalte[n]. Thanks for the help:)

Thanks for the help:)

Comment: You may want to reformat your question, so it is readable.

Comment: You didn't give us information about zeile[i] and spalte

Comment: Question : Is it possible to determine the value of the array by typing and not at the beginning . Additionally the students have a different number of marks thats why zeile has to be different

Comment: zeile [i] should respresent the number of grades spalte[n] should represent the grades example number of grades 3 so {{},{},{}}  marks 3,5,1 ->{{3},{5},{1}}

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
    int studentNumber = in.nextInt();

    int[][] students = new int[studentNumber][];


    for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        int gradeCount = in.nextInt();
        students[i] = new int[gradeCount];
        for (int j = 1; j <= gradeCount; j++) {
            int grade = in.nextInt();
            students[i][j] = grade;
        }
    }
```